# Sorting Topscorecollector Results in Lucene.net?

Tags: lucene.net

I am doing a search operation by using lucene where i was taking my results by using topscorecollector, but i found that it unable to sort my topscorecollector results. I found it quiet odd to sort that. Can we sort the TopscoreCollector results?

My code looks like this

```
        TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(100, true);
        indexSearch.Search(andSearchQuery, filter, collector);
        ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.TopDocs().scoreDocs;
        for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
        {
            int docId = hits[i].doc;
            float score = hits[i].score;
            Lucene.Net.Documents.Document doc = indexSearch.Doc(docId);
            document.Add(doc);
        }
```

Can anybody help me?

Also one more doubt
 we can sort the search results like this

```
Hits hits = IndexSearch.search(searchQuery, filter, sort);
```

But it is showing that Hits become obselete by Lucene 3.0. so i have opted for TopscoreCollector. But now iam very much confused?

If anyother alternate method for Hits, Please pass that to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TopScoreDocCollector` will return results sorted by score. To get results sorted on a field you will need to use a method overload that returns `TopFieldDocs`.

IE: `IndexSearcher.Search(query, filter, nResults, sort)`

If you dont want to limit the number of results use a very large value for the `nResults` parameter. If i remember correctly passing `Int32.MAX_VALUE` will make Lucene generate an exception when initializing its `PriorityQueue` but `Int32.MAX_VALUE-1` is fine.